# Create a jar from MoPub sdk

Tags: java, android, mopub

Recently I implemented the mopub sdk inside of a project, The mopub sdk works fine :)

But, I made the integration as module... I need create mopub.jar and integrate to project

When I try create the .jar with Intellij IDEA exist two parameters (main class and class path), I don't found the main class from mopub sdk

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to integrate as a library project: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html.

The documentation is for eclipse but IDEA should be similar.